# Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Feature with Id 'guid' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope

Tags: 2010, visual-web-part

I have added FeatureEventReceiver to the solution and here is my code,

```
 public override void FeatureInstalled(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {

        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://itcdev33"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
                {

                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    Guid myid = new Guid("32529c03-833d-4c5e-a15e-0bcb35bdedad");
                    if (site.Features[myid] == null)
                    {
                        site.Features.Add(myid, true, SPFeatureDefinitionScope.Site);
                    }
                    web.Update();
                    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: no sharepoint 2010

Comment: Is this a custom feature or is it some inbuilt feature?

Comment: custom solution, custom visual webpart and in that I added featureeventreceiver and in that I have written code in FeatureInstalled

Comment: What feature id is this "32529c03-833d-4c5e-a15e-0bcb35bdedad"

Comment: Ya that's my guid of feature that I have viewed in feature.xml

Answer (score 1):

already answered here:

[Activate a feature in feature installed](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17188/activate-a-feature-in-feature-installed)

issue and why:

> The FeatureInstalled method is called when the WSP is loaded into the
>   Farm and the Feature files are copied into the 12 hive.
>
> This is done in Central Administration or via the command line
>   (Powershell or STSADM). Because of this, there is no website Context
>   to speak of, no site collection or no SPWeb.

solution:

> Then your solution is to have the Feature scoped to Web-Application,
>   your Feature.Parent will be an SPWebApplication object, and you will
>   be able to access the Sites property of that SPWebApplication, which
>   is a collection of SPSite objects. You'll then be able to activate
>   your Site Collection Scoped feature at that level.

Comment: Sorry sir I didn't understood what you said, I am a bit confused. If we make the feature's scope to web-application how would the same feature remain at site collection level?

Comment: I mean I am trying to activate same feature of the sharepoint project while the solution is deployed. And I have added a visual webpart to that solution which I have to add on a web part page so I want that the feature to be activated while the solution is deployed so that I can just add the web part to the web part page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to activate the same feature in the Feature installed event. The feature installation is not yet complete and trying to activate it will cause the error you are seeing.

**UPDATE**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://itcdev33"))
    {
        SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        Guid featureGuid = new Guid("32529c03-833d-4c5e-a15e-0bcb35bdedad");
        web.Features.Add(featureGuid);
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }           
}
```

You can also activate the feature using PowerShell:

```
Enable-SPFeature "32529c03-833d-4c5e-a15e-0bcb35bdedad" -Url "http://itcdev33"
```

Comment: Ok Thanks sir, can you tell me how do I achieve activating a site collection feature programmatically. Since the feature is visible in Site collection features and not yet activated  though the solution is deployed.

Comment: site.Features.Add is the correct method of doing it programmatically. However, as said feature installed event is not the right place to call that code.

Comment: Then where should I call the code in page load?

Comment: What do you mean by page load? Can you provide more information about what you are trying to achieve. May be there is a different way of doing it.

Comment: I have created an empty sharepoint project, in that I have added visual webpart and I have added featureeventreceiver, to the project. And trying to activate the feature when the solution is deployed, I mean programmatically. So is that I have to add an Event receiver to that webpart?

Comment: AFAIK, if only thing in your solution is a single feature and you want to activate the same feature programmatically when the solution is deployed then this is not possible and I have mentioned the reason in the answer. However, if it is possible for you to change the scope to web application, then there is a setting ActivateOnDefault="TRUE" which automatically activates the feature. But is does not apply to Site and Web scoped features.

Comment: Okay, then how to activate a site collection level feature programmatically while its solution is deployed? Or is it not possible at all?

Comment: The idea here is about timing. Once the feature is installed you can activate it. You can write the code in console application.

Comment: Okay, I will give it a try.

Comment: Hi Nadeem, can you tell me how can I achieve doing it through console application. Because I tried doing using SPTool Library it is not happening like that it gives an error, The type or namespace “SPTool” name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)? though I have already deployed an assembly in gac and already added an assembly reference.

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni, see my updated answer.